# Python Code running in Ubuntu 14.04 not running in Windows 8.1/10

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, pymc, weibull

My python code was running successfully in Ubuntu 14.04; but when I went to run in Windows Platform, it throws me into error. The Code:

```
import pylab
import pymc

with open("C:/Users/Anir/Downloads/days1.txt") as f:
    dataset = list(map(float, f))
    a = pymc.Uniform('a', lower=0, upper=1500000, value=70, doc='Weibull alpha parameter')
    b = pymc.Uniform('b', lower=0, upper=1500000, value=70, doc='Weibull beta parameter')
    like = pymc.Weibull('like', alpha=a, beta=b, value=dataset, observed=True)

if __name__=='__main__':
    M = pymc.MCMC([a,b,like])
    M.sample(10000,5000,2)
    pymc.Matplot.plot(a)
    pymc.Matplot.plot(b)
    M.summary()
    M.write_csv("C:/Users/Anir/Downloads/parameters1.csv")
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Anir\Downloads\weibullEstimationOutData - 1 (Check).py", line 11, in <module>
        like = pymc.Weibull('like', alpha=a, beta=b, value=dataset, observed=True)
    File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pymc\distributions.py", line 320, in __init__
        **arg_dict_out)
    File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pymc\PyMCObjects.py", line 775, in __init__
        if not isinstance(self.logp, float):
    File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pymc\PyMCObjects.py", line 932, in get_logp
        raise ZeroProbability(self.errmsg)
    pymc.Node.ZeroProbability: Stochastic like's value is outside its support, or it forbids its parents' current values.
```

Can you help me fix this please!

Comment: The problem might not be the OS: did you try running this multiple times on Ubuntu and Windows? That error means that the starting values drawn from the uniform distribution resulted in an invalid likelihood calculation

Comment: pymc.Node.ZeroProbability: Stochastic like's value is outside its support,
or it forbids its parents' current values. .....  Check you like value ..